# case statements with two conditions of two different fields

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my scenario... i would like to check if the member has mobile in one table, if yes then to display his mobile.. else to check if he has landline phone from another table... if yes then to display landline... else blank. 
not sure if we can use case statement on comparing two different fields

```
SELECT a.name as name, b.name as parent_name, a.mobile, b.phone, 
case 
     when a.mobile is not null or a.mobile<>'' then a.mobile
 else b.phone
end 
     as phone
FROM family_member a join family_header b where a.name='sam' and a.id=b.match_key;
```

please guide me.. only the first case statement is executed and a.mobile is displayed when available.. but if mobile is not available, the landline is NOT displayed..

Comment: **SQL** is just the query language - it's a standard, but even so, the concrete databases tend to have subtle differences - so it would be really helpful to know what **concrete database system** this is for - `mysql`, `oracle`, `postgresql`, `db2`, `sql-server` or whatever else you're using - please **update your tags** accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `mobile` is an empty string, it is `not null`, so this condition matches all those records where `a.mobile` is an empty string. So my guess is, none of your empty fields are `null`.

Change the condition to:

```
when a.mobile is not null AND a.mobile<>'' then
```

Maybe even better: make the field not nullable, so it always contains a phone number or an empty string. Then you can simplify the condition to:

```
when a.mobile<>'' then
```

Comment: ooops.. the issue was with OR and AND condition mess up.. sorry and thanks.. it works now..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name as name, b.name as parent_name, a.mobile, b.phone, 
case 
     when a.mobile is not null or a.mobile<>'' then a.mobile
 else (CASE 
          when b.phone is not NULL or b.phone<>'' then b.phone
          else '')
end 
     as phone
FROM family_member a join family_header b where a.name='sam' and a.id=b.match_key;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend COALESCE.

```
COALESCE(a.mobile, b.phone, '')
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that in this case if a.mobile is '' COALESCE would return ''

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` is bound to a column only if that column is before the `WHEN` otherwise is free

```
SELECT a.name as name, b.name as parent_name, a.mobile, b.phone
     , CASE WHEN a.mobile is NOT NULL OR a.mobile<>'' THEN a.mobile
            WHEN b.phone  is NOT NULL OR b.phone<>'' THEN b.phone
            ELSE ''
       END AS phone
FROM   family_member a 
       JOIN family_header b 
WHERE  a.name='sam' 
  AND  a.id=b.match_key;
```

Comment: this isnt working... thought i dont see any values in a.mobile and b.phone has values, the b.phone isnt displayed  :(

Comment: @SamuelMathews I created a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/906b4/1) with fake data and it works, can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

If the phone numbers can be an empty string or null then you will want to use a `CASE` statement.  Secondly I do believe you need to use `AND` instead of `OR` in the `CASE`. Also, you did not `JOIN` your tables properly:

```
SELECT a.name as name, b.name as parent_name, 
  CASE WHEN a.mobile is NOT NULL AND a.mobile <> '' THEN a.mobile
       WHEN b.phone is NOT NULL AND b.phone <> '' THEN b.phone
       ELSE '' END AS Phone
FROM family_member a 
INNER JOIN family_header b ON a.id = b.match_key
WHERE a.name = 'sam'
```